# How do you scrape specific paragraph text using find or select in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website that has paragraph content set off by h3 headers. The H3 headers have title content (e.g. make, model, year) and then the following text in a paragraph is what I'm after. Ideally, I'd love to identify the paragraph content using a class but it's all the same class.

Also, I should say, I'm new to this so please forgive stupid questions or inarticulate phrasing.

I've gotten to the point where I can pull the text, altogether but separated by the html paragraph tags. My thoughts are that, (1) if I could somehow turn the content between the paragraph tags into individual items in a list that I could write a loop against that list to amend those items into the database I'm building.

Alternatively, (2) I was wondering if there was some sort of way to pull the sibling paragraph text from paragraphs that follow headers which contain specific text (e.g. Ford 'Models'). I know you can do it with defined id's and classes, but can you identify a specific h3 tag based on the text it contains?

I've been watching youtube and reading forums non-stop for the past couple days. Any feedback, delivered as bluntly as you wish, would be GREATLY appreciated! I'm using beautifulsoup but am happy to do whatever is best for the job.

Thanks!

John

Here is the html -

```
<div class="entry-content bb">                                      
<h4>Pedigree</h4>
<p>This is where the content is for pedigree that I am trying to scrape</p>
<h4>Breed</h4>
<p>This is where the content is for breed that I am trying to scrape</p>
<h4>Origin</h4>
<p>This is where the content is for origin that I am trying to scrape</p>
```

If I could identify with the class alone below is the code I would be using -

```
pedigree_temp = soup.find(class_='pedigree').text
pedigree_final.append(pedigree_temp)
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the HTML. And show us your attempt so far. And the expected output

Comment: Would help if you included the website you're trying to scrape...

Comment: Include website. Also, is it all h4 or only certain ones that need to be considered?

Comment: I'm looking for only specific paragraphs. Using the html I provided as an example, assume I'm looking to pull the paragraph text under "pedigree" and "origin", but not "breed". Albert looks close to the solution I'm looking for (through the use of regex, which I'm not familiar with yet) but it doesnt seem quite there, since it doesnt seem to pull the sibling text after finding the right h4 element. I need to find the correct H4 text, then pull the proceeding paragraph text, save it as a temp variable, then append that data to my datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains to target the content of the h4 tag then use an adjacent sibling combinator (+) to move to the adjacent p. You can use the following syntax to generate the appropriate selector from a list of headers items to search for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="entry-content bb">                                      
<h4>Pedigree</h4>
<p>This is where the content is for pedigree that I am trying to scrape</p>
<h4>Breed</h4>
<p>This is where the content is for breed that I am trying to scrape</p>
<h4>Origin</h4>
<p>This is where the content is for origin that I am trying to scrape</p>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
headers = ['Pedigree', 'Breed']
selector = ', '.join([f'h4:contains("{header}") + p' for header in headers])
print([i.text for i in soup.select(selector)])
```

Comment: This looks perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are a genius! It worked! Now I just need to spend some time understanding the why(which I am looking forward to). This is fantastic. Much appreciated!

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of text in all the paragraph tags from your soup, try:

```
[tag.text for tag in soup.select('p')]
```

Or to get a list of tags containing specific text:

```
import re
for elem in soup(text=re.compile('find me!')):
    print elem.parent
```

Comment: Thank you, Albert! Since you submitted your answer I provided more context with html. Apologies for not including it earlier. I need to study up on regex, as it seems to be integral to solving the problem. From what I can gather so far it seems like I need to pull the "next_sibling" to the H4 header I am able to identify.